# Synomym for untrue love

Tags: synonyms

What is the word that can be used to describe a person who has something in heart and speaks something. Specifically showing fake love and affection.

Answer (score 2):

A *faker, a cheater, a pretender* may fit your description I think.

Answer (score 1):

**[Cupboard love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupboard_love)** is related.

> Cupboard love is an English phrase referring to affection that is given purely to gain a reward.
>
> The term derives from the way in which a cat will give a cupboard containing its food superficial "love" (which is not normally exhibited) when it wants to be fed.
>
> The phrase is most often applied to human activity, for example when a child will say "I love you so much" before or after requesting a treat, for example an ice cream.

Answer (score 0):

A man who trifles with a woman's emotions (almost always with women's emotions) is known as a [**philanderer**](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=philanderer+meaning).